# APEX 5.0.1 Interactive report header column alignment

Tags: oracle-apex-5

- in apex 4.2.3 :

[image]

- in apex 5.0.1 :

[image]

==> Why header alignment not center in apex5 ?

Comment: Perhaps it's in a separate CSS file, rather than on the `style=` attribute?

Comment: The problem is that the alignment of column is ok by a class  "u-tC" but as you see the th tag and the a tag inside without any specific class,  a-IRR-headerLink with text-align: inherit;